# Filtering and selecting groups in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Long question short: How to select among groups that are formed as a result of aggregations?

**Useful detail:** I have indexed 1800 photos' EXIF data, and grouped them using geohash cell filter (i.e. location) and date-histogram aggregation (i.e. time).

So I successfully grouped the photos that are close to each other within a certain distance and taken within a specific time.

But now, I further want to select *among* the groups (*NOT* the individual documents) that contain the field/value pair "Image Software": "Instagram". If I use a filter, it will just return the specific documents, not the groups. What approach can I take?

(It would even be better if I could add another condition to select among the groups, for instance another field/value pair).

The POST below returns the aforementioned groups. I now want to select among the groups that contain the field/value pair "Image Software": "Instagram" and return these groups.

```
POST  account_index/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "geohash_cell": {
          "location": {
            "geohash": "swtcw"
          },
          "neighbors": true,
          "precision": 5
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "zamanlar": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "EXIF DateTimeOriginal",
        "interval": "7d"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "grouped": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is an example of the elements of one of many groups that are returned as a result of the POST above:

```
    {
 "took": 3,
 "timed_out": false,
 "_shards": {
  "total": 5,
  "successful": 5,
   "failed": 0
 },
 "hits": {
  "total": 136,
  "max_score": 0,
  "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
  "zamanlar": {
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key_as_string": "2015:06:11 00:00:00",
           "key": 1433980800000,
           "doc_count": 30,
           "ohy": {
              "hits": {
                 "total": 30,
                 "max_score": 1,
                 "hits": [
                    {
                       "_index": "account_index",
                       "_type": "image",
                       "_id": "1356",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "GPS GPSTimeStamp": "[16, 35, 697/20]",
                          "Thumbnail YResolution": "72",
                          "GPS GPSLongitudeRef": "E",
                          "GPS GPSLongitude": "[30, 52, 2249/50]",
                          "EXIF DateTimeOriginal": "2015:06:15 19:35:35",
                          "Image Model": "iPhone 5",
                          "EXIF LensModel": "iPhone 5 back camera 4.12mm f/2.4",
                          "GPS GPSLatitudeRef": "N",
                          "FileName": "IMG_0613.JPG",
                          "CalculatedLatitude": 36.85336388888889,
                          "CalculatedLongitude": 30.879161111111113,
                          "location": {
                             "lat": 36.85336388888889,
                             "lon": 30.879161111111113
                          },
                          "EXIF ExifImageLength": "2448",
                          "Image Make": "Apple",
                          "EXIF ExifImageWidth": "3264",
                          "GPS GPSLatitude": "[36, 51, 1211/100]",
                          "Image Software": "7.1.2",
                          "GPS GPSAltitude": "6217/1147",
                          "Thumbnail XResolution": "72"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "_index": "account_index",
                       "_type": "image",
                       "_id": "1363",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "GPS GPSTimeStamp": "[12, 28, 1356/25]",
                          "Thumbnail YResolution": "72",
                          "GPS GPSLongitudeRef": "E",
                          "GPS GPSLongitude": "[30, 52, 2193/50]",
                          "EXIF DateTimeOriginal": "2015:06:16 15:28:55",
                          "Image Model": "iPhone 5",
                          "EXIF LensModel": "iPhone 5 back camera 4.12mm f/2.4",
                          "GPS GPSLatitudeRef": "N",
                          "FileName": "IMG_0620.JPG",
                          "CalculatedLatitude": 36.85424166666667,
                          "CalculatedLongitude": 30.87885,
                          "location": {
                             "lat": 36.85424166666667,
                             "lon": 30.87885
                          },
                          "EXIF ExifImageLength": "2448",
                          "Image Make": "Apple",
                          "EXIF ExifImageWidth": "3264",
                          "GPS GPSLatitude": "[36, 51, 1527/100]",
                          "Image Software": "7.1.2",
                          "GPS GPSAltitude": "0",
                          "Thumbnail XResolution": "72"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "_index": "account_index",
                       "_type": "image",
                       "_id": "1368",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "GPS GPSTimeStamp": "[17, 28, 1767/50]",
                          "Thumbnail YResolution": "72",
                          "GPS GPSLongitudeRef": "E",
                          "GPS GPSLongitude": "[30, 52, 1097/25]",
                          "EXIF DateTimeOriginal": "2015:06:16 20:28:36",
                          "Image Model": "iPhone 5",
                          "EXIF LensModel": "iPhone 5 back camera 4.12mm f/2.4",
                          "GPS GPSLatitudeRef": "N",
                          "FileName": "IMG_0625.JPG",
                          "CalculatedLatitude": 36.85438888888889,
                          "CalculatedLongitude": 30.878855555555557,
                          "location": {
                             "lat": 36.85438888888889,
                             "lon": 30.878855555555557
                          },
                          "EXIF ExifImageLength": "2448",
                          "Image Make": "Apple",
                          "EXIF ExifImageWidth": "3264",
                          "GPS GPSLatitude": "[36, 51, 79/5]",
                          "Image Software": "7.1.2",
                          "GPS GPSAltitude": "0",
                          "Thumbnail XResolution": "72"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "_index": "account_index",
                       "_type": "image",
                       "_id": "1370",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "GPS GPSTimeStamp": "[17, 28, 749/20]",
                          "Thumbnail YResolution": "72",
                          "GPS GPSLongitudeRef": "E",
                          "GPS GPSLongitude": "[30, 52, 1097/25]",
                          "EXIF DateTimeOriginal": "2015:06:16 20:28:38",
                          "Image Model": "iPhone 5",
                          "EXIF LensModel": "iPhone 5 back camera 4.12mm f/2.4",
                          "GPS GPSLatitudeRef": "N",
                          "FileName": "IMG_0627.JPG",
                          "CalculatedLatitude": 36.85438888888889,
                          "CalculatedLongitude": 30.878855555555557,
                          "location": {
                             "lat": 36.85438888888889,
                             "lon": 30.878855555555557
                          },
                          "EXIF ExifImageLength": "2448",
                          "Image Make": "Apple",
                          "EXIF ExifImageWidth": "3264",
                          "GPS GPSLatitude": "[36, 51, 79/5]",
                          "Image Software": "7.1.2",
                          "GPS GPSAltitude": "0",
                          "Thumbnail XResolution": "72"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "_index": "account_index",
                       "_type": "image",
                       "_id": "1375",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "GPS GPSTimeStamp": "[19, 19, 112/5]",
                          "Thumbnail YResolution": "72",
                          "GPS GPSLongitudeRef": "E",
                          "GPS GPSLongitude": "[30, 52, 4469/100]",
                          "EXIF DateTimeOriginal": "2015:06:16 22:19:23",
                          "Image Model": "iPhone 5",
                          "EXIF LensModel": "iPhone 5 back camera 4.12mm f/2.4",
                          "GPS GPSLatitudeRef": "N",
                          "FileName": "IMG_0632.JPG",
                          "CalculatedLatitude": 36.85251944444445,
                          "CalculatedLongitude": 30.879080555555557,
                          "location": {
                             "lat": 36.85251944444445,
                             "lon": 30.879080555555557
                          },
                          "EXIF ExifImageLength": "2448",
                          "Image Make": "Apple",
                          "EXIF ExifImageWidth": "3264",
                          "GPS GPSLatitude": "[36, 51, 907/100]",
                          "Image Software": "7.1.2",
                          "GPS GPSAltitude": "8555/2048",
                          "Thumbnail XResolution": "72"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "_index": "account_index",
                       "_type": "image",
                       "_id": "1382",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "GPS GPSTimeStamp": "[19, 22, 119/5]",
                          "Thumbnail YResolution": "72",
                          "GPS GPSLongitudeRef": "E",
                          "GPS GPSLongitude": "[30, 52, 4487/100]",
                          "EXIF DateTimeOriginal": "2015:06:16 22:22:24",
                          "Image Model": "iPhone 5",
                          "EXIF LensModel": "iPhone 5 back camera 4.12mm f/2.4",
                          "GPS GPSLatitudeRef": "N",
                          "FileName": "IMG_0639.JPG",
                          "CalculatedLatitude": 36.852516666666666,
                          "CalculatedLongitude": 30.879130555555555,
                          "location": {
                             "lat": 36.852516666666666,
                             "lon": 30.879130555555555
                          },
                          "EXIF ExifImageLength": "2448",
                          "Image Make": "Apple",
                          "EXIF ExifImageWidth": "3264",
                          "GPS GPSLatitude": "[36, 51, 453/50]",
                          "Image Software": "7.1.2",
                          "GPS GPSAltitude": "0",
                          "Thumbnail XResolution": "72"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "_index": "account_index",
                       "_type": "image",
                       "_id": "1357",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "GPS GPSTimeStamp": "[16, 35, 921/25]",
                          "Thumbnail YResolution": "72",
                          "GPS GPSLongitudeRef": "E",
                          "GPS GPSLongitude": "[30, 52, 2249/50]",
                          "EXIF DateTimeOriginal": "2015:06:15 19:35:37",
                          "Image Model": "iPhone 5",
                          "EXIF LensModel": "iPhone 5 back camera 4.12mm f/2.4",
                          "GPS GPSLatitudeRef": "N",
                          "FileName": "IMG_0614.JPG",
                          "CalculatedLatitude": 36.85336388888889,
                          "CalculatedLongitude": 30.879161111111113,
                          "location": {
                             "lat": 36.85336388888889,
                             "lon": 30.879161111111113
                          },
                          "EXIF ExifImageLength": "2448",
                          "Image Make": "Apple",
                          "EXIF ExifImageWidth": "3264",
                          "GPS GPSLatitude": "[36, 51, 1211/100]",
                          "Image Software": "7.1.2",
                          "GPS GPSAltitude": "5153/1024",
                          "Thumbnail XResolution": "72"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "_index": "account_index",
                       "_type": "image",
                       "_id": "1364",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "GPS GPSTimeStamp": "[12, 29, 29/25]",
                          "Thumbnail YResolution": "72",
                          "GPS GPSLongitudeRef": "E",
                          "GPS GPSLongitude": "[30, 52, 877/20]",
                          "EXIF DateTimeOriginal": "2015:06:16 15:29:01",
                          "Image Model": "iPhone 5",
                          "EXIF LensModel": "iPhone 5 back camera 4.12mm f/2.4",
                          "GPS GPSLatitudeRef": "N",
                          "FileName": "IMG_0621.JPG",
                          "CalculatedLatitude": 36.85424722222222,
                          "CalculatedLongitude": 30.878847222222223,
                          "location": {
                             "lat": 36.85424722222222,
                             "lon": 30.878847222222223
                          },
                          "EXIF ExifImageLength": "2448",
                          "Image Make": "Apple",
                          "EXIF ExifImageWidth": "3264",
                          "GPS GPSLatitude": "[36, 51, 1529/100]",
                          "Image Software": "7.1.2",
                          "GPS GPSAltitude": "0",
                          "Thumbnail XResolution": "72"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "_index": "account_index",
                       "_type": "image",
                       "_id": "1369",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "GPS GPSTimeStamp": "[17, 28, 749/20]",
                          "Thumbnail YResolution": "72",
                          "GPS GPSLongitudeRef": "E",
                          "GPS GPSLongitude": "[30, 52, 1097/25]",
                          "EXIF DateTimeOriginal": "2015:06:16 20:28:38",
                          "Image Model": "iPhone 5",
                          "EXIF LensModel": "iPhone 5 back camera 4.12mm f/2.4",
                          "GPS GPSLatitudeRef": "N",
                          "FileName": "IMG_0626.JPG",
                          "CalculatedLatitude": 36.85438888888889,
                          "CalculatedLongitude": 30.878855555555557,
                          "location": {
                             "lat": 36.85438888888889,
                             "lon": 30.878855555555557
                          },
                          "EXIF ExifImageLength": "2448",
                          "Image Make": "Apple",
                          "EXIF ExifImageWidth": "3264",
                          "GPS GPSLatitude": "[36, 51, 79/5]",
                          "Image Software": "7.1.2",
                          "GPS GPSAltitude": "0",
                          "Thumbnail XResolution": "72"
                       }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to make it work simply by wrapping your existing aggregation into a [`filter` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) like this:

```
POST  account_index/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "geohash_cell": {
          "location": {
            "geohash": "swtcw"
          },
          "neighbors": true,
          "precision": 5
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "zamanlar": {
      "filter": {               <------ wrap your aggregation into this new filter aggregation
        "term": {
          "Image Software": "Instagram"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "zamanlar": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "EXIF DateTimeOriginal",
            "interval": "7d"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "grouped": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 10000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But now it gives me this, which is not possible. Is there a chance the order of aggs is wrong? Desired: Location filter-->Time filter -->Field Filter `{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 136,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "zamanlar": {
         "doc_count": 0,
         "zamanlar": {
            "buckets": []
         }
      }
   }
}`

Comment: It also depends on your mapping for the `"Image Software"` field (i.e. is it analyzed or not), maybe try with `instagram` (lowercase)  instead.

Comment: Its mapping "type" is "string". And also I checked again, EXIF definitely writes with the Uppercase letter "Instagram". Doesn't this `"term": {
          "Image Software": "Instagram"
        }` look for individual elements instead of inside groups? I am trying to return groups who have AT LEAST ONE element that has the pair "Image Software":"Instagram" (i.e. the whole group elements don't necessarily have to have this tag). Just one element is OK.